# Angular 8 issue with directive on component html

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have created a directive using angular 8.

Directive code:

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDynamic]',
  exportAs: 'dynamicdirective'
})
export class DynamicDirective {

  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

}
```

Then I added it to my component ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-preview',
  templateUrl: './preview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./preview.component.scss']
})
export class PreviewComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('sider', {static: true})
  sider;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(PreviewComponent);
    this.sider.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  }

}
```

And finally I added the code to the component's html which is where I'm getting the error:

```
<ng-template #sider="dynamicdirective" dynamic></ng-template>
```

The line of code above is giving me the following error:

```
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "dynamicdirective"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you added it in your app.module file?

Comment: yes it was added automatically by the cli

Comment: Should I change its name for it to work? The cli gave it that name in camel case

Comment: Shouldn't you set the directive with `appDynamic` instead of `dynamic`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your selector is appDynamic, you need set the directive with that.

```
<ng-template #sider="dynamicdirective" appDynamic></ng-template>
```